# How to subtract hours from a calendar instance

Tags: java

Based on my understanding of the `roll()` method, I expected the below code to subtract 140 hours from the current time.  But it seems to be subtracting 20 hours.  Is this not the proper way to do this?

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
rightNow.roll(Calendar.HOUR, -140);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll%28int,%20int%29), the `roll` method does not change **larger fields** and it will roll the hour value in the range between 0 and 23.

So in your case, considering HOUR_OF_DAY, 140 is actually considered as (24 * 5) + 20 = 140. Now since it does not change larger fields the "hour" is rolled back by 24 hours 5 times which gets it back to the same time and then it rolls it back by 20 hours.

To achieve a "real" 140 hours roll back you can do it like -

```
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR, -140);
```

Comment: isn't Calendar.HOUR a unit of time of 12hours (0-11). So it's (12 * 11) + 8 = 140, rolling back 8 hrs? Or did OP mean HOUR_OF_DAY vs HOUR

Comment: Good catch. By HOUR its a 8 hour rollback and by HOUR_OF_DAY it would be a 20 hour rollback.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the date in a Calendar object called 'rightNow' you can use the following code:

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
rightNow.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -numberOfHours);
```

Where:

> **numberOfHours:** Is the amount of hours you want to subtract.

Answer (score 0):

Roll depends on implementation, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll%28int,%20int%29

Probably your default implementation rolls maximum one day. Rather to use GregorianCalendar or Joda http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/.